# Visual Studio 2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, unresolved-external

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _imp_strtod
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _imp__dclass
```

My project is in C and in my existing C project, I am trying to integrate this JSON library as a source file [Jansson_parser](https://github.com/akheron/jansson) while building the whole project I'm getting this above error.

If anyone knows how to resolve please help me.

Comment: There must be a problem with the some options in your .vcproj file. Try to temporarily remove all code from the project and make a Hello world program that uses just one `strtod`, see if this builds and report back.

Comment: These symbols are defined by the C runtime library.  Not linking it is hard to do, check Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code generation > "Runtime library" setting.  The library insists you use the default here (/MD).

Comment: Thanks, will check on this

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, I changed the setting to /MD previous it was /Mtd. Now build was success!